# How do I clean up this mesh?

Tags: modeling

I beveled this edge on the mesh and tried to fix the topology so i could apply another bevel modifier to some edges, but i still struggle to understand how the mesh works. How can i solve these issues?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=PE1yx0ba" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/PE1yx0ba/) Is this what you wanted? i did some changes.